# Multiple parameters in ui-router state URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use multiple parameters in a ui-router state url?

**Take note of `id` and `game_id` in example below**

```
.state('games', {
    url: 'users/{id}/games/{game_id}',
    templateUrl: 'games/_game.html',
    controller: 'GameCtrl'
})
```

When I try to navigate to a URL like, `app.io/users/1/games/2` it automatically redirects off of the page so I'm wondering if its not possible?

Comment: Are you using html5 based url? if not then you need to specify hash based url there like: `app.io/#/users/1/games/2`

Comment: Check the value of the params

Comment: May be you need to mention the params like this: `'users/:id/games/:game_id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question - yes its possible.
My error was using incorrect syntax.

**I did this**

```
.state('games', {
    url: 'users/{id}/games/{game_id}',
    templateUrl: 'games/_game.html',
    controller: 'GameCtrl'
})
```

**But should have done this**

```
.state('games', {
    url: '/users/{id}/games/{game_id}',
    templateUrl: 'games/_game.html',
    controller: 'GameCtrl'
})
```

Note the `/` at the beginning of the string passed to `url:`. This `/` is required to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To specify url parameters in angular-ui-router you need to use `:param` not `{param}`.

```
.state('games', {
    url: 'users/:id/games/:game_id',
    templateUrl: 'games/_game.html',
    controller: 'GameCtrl'
})
```

Please consult their documentation for more examples.

Comment: I think both `{}` and `:` work. but i was missing a `/` infront of the url, `/users/:id/games/:game_id`